# Cover element on LED component

Tags: led, automotive, semiconductors

From time to time I come across a solution in which uses an LED as in below picture:

[image]

This particular component is placed inside the module located in car interior. Button backlight application.

The base LED [PLCC-2 Package] is blue color LED. The top cover material changes the light to white, so I assume this cover material is actually a phosphorus layer. This is a common approach of achieving white color but usually the phosphorus layer is integrated inside the PLCC-2 package (The die is sunk in phosphorus line on below picture.)

[image]

What is the purpose of this additional cover?
My guesses are:

- Specially mixed phosphorus layer is added to finished LED in order to achieve exact white color coordinates.
- Manufacturing process improvement: one line for blue and white LEDs with additional process for white.

Is there any LED expert that could confirm this?

Comment: Does it not simply shine at the bottom side? I.e. flip chip?

Comment: @winny No, underneath the phosphorus layer there is a standard PLCC-2 blue LED. This assembly shines in a standard way 90 degree angle to PCB surface.

Comment: Then I don’t understand your question. Are you asking why the phosphorus layer is there?

Comment: The question is why the phosphorus layer is not directly on a die as on Picture number two, which is much simpler from production point of view.

Comment: I can't tell from the photo but the most common answer to all questions of this type is: price. If it makes it cheaper in any way, someone will do it.

Comment: That is one of my guesses too, I hope someone from LED manufacturing industry could confirm this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received confirmation from LED supplier:

- This solution results in better light homogeneity than die sinking method.
- It is very rare because it's patent protected.